# Unfairly closed question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I can see this getting alot of negative votes, if not closed/deleted, but I feel like my question was closed unfairly. It <del>is now</del> <del>had been</del> has again been deleted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154097/regex-to-split-by-and-n

My question was basically that I need a regex to split between spaces, semicolons, and new lines. Did you find that hard to understand? (as the close message stated).

According to the FAQS

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

My question was a specific programming problem
It is practical to me, it is answerable (there were 2 answers), and I don't see where it is used other than programming.

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and
>   push other questions off the front page.

It wasn't open-ended

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

It did not take a whole book, not even more than a line or two.

There is other things I could point out, but it is useless now. Main point is, my question followed the guidelines.

I did write a few fair comments (in a semi-polite manner, not rudely, I just wanted an answer as to why it was closed)

And lastly, 90% of the time I google a question, and come on to stackoverflow, the question has been closed. These aren't silly questions, they are direct and following the guidelines as mine was.

Honestly, a private message or response as to why it was closed would make me feel 100x better than not knowing what I did wrong, atleast I could then improve... I think you are missing that point.

Comment: I guess it is not forbidden to remove the not-so-clever remark, which attracted the downvotes, to put the question in a better light. I just did so. Btw.: If you learn regexes, you will save so much time, that you have enough time to learn new things. Nothing pays off like regexes - except unix pipes. Or unix-pipes plus regex. And 10 finger blind typing.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I've never heard of a unix pipe, but I will look at that also.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why people made such a big deal in your question about what you say that you do/don't have time to learn. In certain realms of programming that don't really involve much string manipulation, you can get along without regexes perfectly fine. Programming is such a huge field, and there's thousands of things that could be useful to learn, but I don't think anybody actually has the time to learn them all.

Comment: You don't need a regex to split.  That's what `split` (or the equivalent function in whatever language you're using) is for.

Comment: The split method takes in a regex as a parameter. The language is java.

Comment: Yes, the regex parameter for the `split` method is a pattern for the delimiter upon which to split.  That's not the same as trying to split a string via a regex.

Comment: I am using the split method if that's what you're saying. Did I phrase my question wrong?

Comment: @userunknown "And 10 finger blind typing." So true!

Comment: I only type with 5 fingers, excluding backspaces and spaces, but that is fast enough for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your question starts with:

> I don't have time to learn regex's at the momement

The community has little patience with people who ask for help but don't have the time to learn the basics.

I expect that is why your question ended up being closed and deleted.

Comment: Thank your for the response, much appreciated =), I would have thought it was a very trivial matter since it is so simple. It is something I have to learn eventually, but I really am short on time at the moment, and I just want to finish this project quickly. I will keep that in mind though. Anyway, I have my answer, and understand what was wrong.

Comment: @AlexisReyori - Point is that yes, the question was closed unfairly, but your tone when asking just put people off... And people many times vote by gut reaction rather then what's in the FAQ.

Comment: I've never really considered tone when talking, I will keep that in mind though. Thanks.

Comment: Rephrase to *"I would prefer a solution that did not involve regular expressions"* and locate strategically towards the *end* of the question, after you've already explained your problem that you want solved. @ale

Comment: But, this isn't the only problem, @Oded. Even once you remove that line (or rephrase it), the question remains problematic. He's basically asking someone to write code for him, and that's not what Stack Overflow is for. We're not a code-writing service. You need to show some effort at having tried to solve the problem yourself and should not expect answers that provide complete code-ready solutions.

Comment: Well, I didn't have a preference over using regexes, as I wasn't familiar with any other methods. It is a very basic code parser. As for asking you to write code, I have overlooked that, trivial or not. It still seems like a small enough case like: 'How do I make a string?' I have tried aaaa (without quotes), where the attempt would still be irrelevant. If I was asking how to make some collision, or GUI code, then I would have posted my attempt. A simple "What have you tried so far?" would have sufficed in any case. You can probably close this now, it has gone on long enough.

Comment: I don't understand why people are still downvoting, for the inital thread, fair enough. But here I am just asking why it was (with some misunderstandings), is that bad? It's not worthy of an upvote of course.

Comment: @Alexis: [Voting is a bit different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq/#vote-differences). People probably agree that the original question is a bad one, and therefore they disagree with this question, which posits that it was closed "unfairly".

Comment: I suppose that's true, although the original question can't be seen if it was removed, but maybe it's the ones with privelages. I'm not concerned anyhow. Thanks. I'm going to stop looking at this thread now since everything has been worked out. I have my answer, and know why it was closed, as well as learning a few small additional things. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Nevermind the first part of my above comment, I misinterpreted The Establishments statement.